# HTTPS doesn't work with my www subdomain CNAME

Tags: web, github, https, cname

I'm using GitHub Pages for my site.

1. https://spellbot.io works
2. http://spellbot.io redirects to #1
3. http://www.spellbot.io redirects to #1

The problem is when I combine www and https. It gives me a "Connection is Not Private" warning saying that the certificate is not valid. The certificate it shows is a DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA from [www.github.com](http://www.github.com).

On my site's DNS configuration I have a CNAME set to point www at spellbot.io, and I have a CAA record for spellbot.io that uses letsencrypt.org.

I followed all the instructions that GitHub gives here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-an-apex-domain

I have setup my the A records properly. I have a CNAME file in my GitHub Pages directory with "spellbot.io" in it. And I have checked to turn on "Enforce HTTPS" in my repo settings.

How on earth do I make this work correctly?